# Can we convert between arrays and structs without constructing "manually"?

Tags: go

I have a struct to represent a vector in 3D space.

```
type Vec3 struct {
    X, Y, Z float64
}
```

Another library I am using does something similar, but different:

```
type Vector [3]float64
```

From my understanding, both types should occupy 24 bytes and each `float64` in one type should line up with a `float64` in the other type. So, we should be able to assign from one to the other without too much trouble. The compiler however does not like trying to cast these neither implicity nor explicitly, so the cleanest (but verbose) method appears to be to always construct the value manually:

```
// Vec3 to Vector
vec3 := Vec3{1, 2, 3}
vector := Vector{vec3.X, vec3.Y, vec3.Z}

// Vector to Vec3
vector := Vector{1, 2, 3}
vec3 := Vec3{vector[0], vector[1], vector[2]}
```

Another method I found is the following, but it looks no less verbose (and probably slower (and it won't stop us if one of the types ever changes)).

```
valueOfTargetType := *(*targetType)(unsafe.Pointer(&sourceValue))
```

So, can we cast these without explicitly constructing a new value?

Comment: Given that there is no references in Go - I think it's impossible to have 2 distinct variables that are backed by the same storage.

Comment: To clarify: The library I use has functions of the form `AddVector(vec Vector)`, meaning that yes, I have to copy anyway. What I intend to do is make supplying `Vec3d` instead of `[3]float64` introduce no reduction in performance, and no increase in code complexity. Performance-loss should be avoidable since the memory layout of the two types is identical.

Comment: After some back and forth I have realized my question is really more concerned with code semantics rather than with performance and I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a concise solution, which will be inlined, use methods.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vec3 struct {
    X, Y, Z float64
}

func (v Vec3) Vector() Vector {
    return Vector{v.X, v.Y, v.Z}
}

type Vector [3]float64

func (v Vector) Vec3() Vec3 {
    return Vec3{X: v[0], Y: v[1], Z: v[2]}
}

func main() {
    v3 := Vec3{X: 1, Y: 2, Z: 3}
    v3v := v3.Vector()
    fmt.Println(v3, v3v)

    v := Vector{4, 5, 6}
    vv3 := v.Vec3()
    fmt.Println(v, vv3)
}
```

Output:

```
{1 2 3} [1 2 3]
[4 5 6] {4 5 6}
```

Comment: > which *will* be inlined  --  That's what I like to read. :p

Comment: Won't calls to `Vec3.Vector()` and `Vector.Vec3()` allocate new memory _every_ call? They're being recreated with the type literal construction and then `return`ed by value each time, so "copying" is still in effect.

Answer (score 2):

> convert between arrays and structs without copying?

Nope.

> What I intend to do is make supplying Vec3d instead of [3]float64 introduce no reduction in performance

Given that its impossible to convert arrays to structs without copying, I'd suggest to front-load your copying of `type Vec3` -> `[3]float64` at the start of the program so you won't experience any penalties during the main loop.

> assign from one to the other without copying (or other slow overhead)

Consider completing the program first to see if performance is acceptable to the end-users.

In my experience working with 3d vectors, it's the *application of 3d transforms* on the vectors that's the real performance killer. Try running a profiler afterward to check which part of processing would produce the most bang for your development time.

Hope this helps. Cheers,

Comment: Now I feel kinda bad that my question has changed almost entirely while you were writing your answer. I'll accept it later if it's the best we're going to get.